# Adding to custom linked list causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, custom-component

So, adding stuff to my *custom* linked list is causing a `NullPointerException`, and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why. The purpose of the program is to simulate a chest of drawers, with a list that has the drawers as nodes. The drawers each have a list that includes household objects as nodes.

Here's the relevant bits of code. The error happens when I create a: `new ChestOfDrawers(3);` in my UI class:

```
public class ChestOfDrawers{

    private static OwnList chest;  
    private static int[] parametres;

    public ChestOfDrawers (int drawers){
        chest = new OwnList();
        create();
    }

    public static void create(){
        for (int i = 0; i < parametres.length; i++) {
            Object drawer = new Drawer(i, parametres[i]);
            chest.add(i, drawer); //This is causing the error
        }   
    }
}
```

The `Drawer` class being referred to here is the class for the drawers. It requires `int i` as an ID and `int parametres` as drawer capacity. The `parametres[]` array gets filled before the additions to the list are made and it includes info for drawer capacity. The linked list in the question (`OwnList`) is functioning 100% correctly as it is part of a provided course material, it's near identical to Java's own. I tested the class in another test class and it worked fine, I've just made a mistake here somewhere. Please help!

Comment: Why are you using `static` members here?

Comment: To be able to reference them from a static context, that's not relevant however

Comment: Maybe not.  But it's unlikely that this code makes much sense; every time you create a new object, you'll be overwriting the static references.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are not initializing the parametres array. This field will be null by default. You need to either initialize it where it is declared, or in a static initializer block. Additionally, why are the two fields and the create method static? Those certainly seem like instance state...

Here's a better version:

```
public final class ChestOfDrawers{
    private final OwnList chest = new OwnList();  
    private final int[] parametres;

public ChestOfDrawers (int drawers){
    if (drawers < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Drawers may not be negative");
    chest = new OwnList();
    parametres = new int[drawers]; // <-- I'm assuming that's the intended meaning
    initialize();
}        

private void initialize(){
    for(int i = 0; i < parametres.length; i++){
        Object drawer = new Drawer(i, parametres[i]); // <-- parametres[i] will always be 0
        chest.add(i, drawer); 
    }   
}
}
```

I'm not sure what you need the parametres array to actually contain (a new array of int will be filled with zero values) - but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader :-)